# RegEx only text between the tags

Tags: php, regex, removing-whitespace

What I need to fix here:

```
(<.*?>\s*)([^<.*?>]*\S\s*?)(\s*?<.*?>)
```

for only the text was in a group (without whitespaces) and look for it between the tags (`<...> <...>`)? For Example: [image: RegTest]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic regex that works

`(?<=<)[^>]*`

`(?<=<)` this is a lookbehind assertion. Basically, it only matches when the previous character is a '<'

`[^>]*` this matches everything up until a '>'. Alternatively you can use `[^\r\n]` to make sure you don't do multi line matches.

Edit:

Alternative regex

`(?<=<)[^>]+` This stops it from matching zero length strings ie <> will not match

`(?<=<)[^>\n\r]+` This stops it from matching across new lines and zero length strings.

`(?<=<)[^>]*` This matches any and everything between '<' and '>'